# Attaching ZMQStream with existing tornado ioloop

Tags: python, tornado, zeromq

I have an application where every websocket connection (within tornado open callback) creates a `zmq.SUB` socket to an existing `zmq.FORWARDER` device. Idea is to receive data from zmq as callbacks, which can then be relayed to frontend clients over websocket connection.

https://gist.github.com/abhinavsingh/6378134

**ws.py**

```
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream
ioloop.install()

from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
ioloop = IOLoop.instance()

class ZMQPubSub(object):

    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

    def connect(self):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5560')
        self.stream = ZMQStream(self.socket)
        self.stream.on_recv(self.callback)

    def subscribe(self, channel_id):
        self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, channel_id)

class MyWebSocket(WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        self.pubsub = ZMQPubSub(self.on_data)
        self.pubsub.connect()
        self.pubsub.subscribe("session_id")
        print 'ws opened'

    def on_message(self, message):
        print message

    def on_close(self):
        print 'ws closed'

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data

def main():
    application = Application([(r'/channel', MyWebSocket)])
    application.listen(10001)
    print 'starting ws on port 10001'
    ioloop.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**forwarder.py**

```
import zmq

def main():
    try:
        context = zmq.Context(1)

        frontend = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        frontend.bind('tcp://*:5559')
        frontend.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')

        backend = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        backend.bind('tcp://*:5560')

        print 'starting zmq forwarder'
        zmq.device(zmq.FORWARDER, frontend, backend)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
    finally:
        frontend.close()
        backend.close()
        context.term()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**publish.py**

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5559')
    socket.send('session_id helloworld')
    print 'sent data for channel session_id'
```

However, my `ZMQPubSub` class doesn't seem like is receiving any data at all.

I further experimented and realized that I need to call `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` after registering `on_recv` callback within `ZMQPubSub`. But, that will just block the execution.

I also tried passing `main.ioloop` instance to `ZMQStream` constructor but doesn't help either.

Is there a way by which I can bind `ZMQStream` to existing `main.ioloop` instance without blocking flow within `MyWebSocket.open`?

Comment: what pyzmq and tornado versions are you using?  I just tested your code with current master of both, and the PubSub object is indeed receiving messages.

Comment: `tornado==3.1` `pyzmq==13.1.0`

Comment: @minrk I have updated sample code to reflect of what exactly is being tried at my end. Are you able to get this sample code running at your end and receive data within `on_data` callback?

Comment: Does your publisher really just bind/send/exit as fast as it can?  Because slow-subscribers will never receive that message as subscriptions won't propagate before the first message is sent.  You can add a sleep before `publisher.send`, and your message should arrive.

Comment: @minrk Thanks for the sleep tip, that certainly helped.

Yes publishers in my application will mostly connect/send/exit. However, this sleep is really an unwanted thing here. Is there a way to ensure reliable delivery of messages without any sleep involved?

Comment: If you switch from PUB to XPUB, you can wait for subscribers before you send.  Depending on your connection pattern, it may also be true that PUSH/PULL is actually a better fit for your use case.  Can you provide a bit more detail about the lifecycle of each service?

Comment: @minrk Thanks Min for the reply. Goal of the application is to enable a language agnostic way to push data to web clients from anywhere within the infrastructure e.g. from worker threads or even shell. So ideally, web clients will subscribe to a number of default channels and publishers will just connect/send/exit in most cases. I am relatively new to zmq patterns and still digging into zmq docs to find why a 1 msec sleep was helpful here (wasn't obvious to me). Sleep is surely undesirable here or probably I should use different zmq pattern.

Comment: The slow joiner syndrome is covered in [chapter one of the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out).  Given that you want a sort of fire-and-forget model, PUSH is probably a better fit.  How many clients should receive any given message? If it is really PUB-SUB, then presumably each message should arrive at several endpoints, is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your now complete example, simply change `frontend` in your forwarder to a PULL socket and your publisher socket to PUSH, and it should behave as you expect.

The general principles of socket choice that are relevant here:

- use PUB/SUB when you want to send a message to everyone who is ready to receive it (may be no one)
- use PUSH/PULL when you want to send a message to exactly one peer, waiting for them to be ready

it may appear initially that you just want PUB-SUB, but once you start looking at each socket pair, you realize that they are very different.  The `frontend-websocket` connection is definitely PUB-SUB - you may have zero-to-many receivers, and you just want to send messages to everyone who happens to be available when a message comes through.  But the backend side is different - there is only one receiver, and it definitely wants every message from the publishers.

So there you have it - backend should be PULL and frontend PUB.  All your sockets:

```
PUSH -> [PULL-PUB] -> SUB
```

publisher.py: socket is `PUSH`, connected to `backend` in device.py

forwarder.py: `backend` is `PULL`, `frontend` is `PUB`
ws.py: `SUB` connects and subscribes to `forwarder.frontend`.

The relevant behavior that makes PUB/SUB fail on the backend in your case is the **slow joiner syndrome**, which is [described in The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Getting-the-Message-Out). Essentially, subscribers take a finite time to tell publishers about there subscriptions, so if you send a message immediately after opening a PUB socket, the odds are it hasn't been told that it has any subscribers yet, so it's just discarding messages.

Comment: I probably wasn't too clear with my explanation in the last reply. I see you proposing to replace forwarder (pub/sub) with a streamer (push/pull) device (correct me if wrong). However, my use case will need a pub/sub based solution. Each websocket connection default subscribes to atleast 3 channels a) `all_channels` b) `${session_id}_channels` c) `${session_id}_channel_${tab_id}`. In practice, c) can make use of push/pull but a) and b) both will need pub/sub strategy. Makes sense?

Comment: No, I am not proposing that you replace it with a PUSH/PULL device - only replace the SUB in the device with PULL, and the publisher service with PUSH - that way, the whole chain is: `PUSH -> PULL-PUB -> SUB-websocket`.  You have a PULL-PUB device, not PULL-PUSH or SUB-PUB.

Answer (score 1):

ZeroMq subscribers have to subscribe on what messages they wish to receive; I don't see that in your code. I believe the Python way is this:

```
self.socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
```

Comment: I forgot to add that bit in the question above. Websocket connection do subscribe to a set of channel_id's. I have updated the code above to reflect the same.